# Spawn another python process and get its return object

Tags: python

Say that you have a singleton to play with (which means that the only way to initialize that to original state is to restart the whole script) and you want to do a specific tasks multiple times on this and get the returned objects. Are there any ways I can do this without disk I/O? I know I can do that with `subprocess.check_output()` like [How to spawn another process and capture output in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572341/how-to-spawn-another-process-and-capture-output-in-python) and file I/O or piping `stdio`, but are there any cleaner solutions as simple as same-process communications (Edit: I mean, `result = foo()`)?

```
#the singleton
def foo():
    crash_when_got_run_twice()
    result = something_fancy()
    return result

#the runner
def bar(times):
    for i in range(times):
        result = magic() # run foo()
        aggregate_result(result)
    return aggregated_result()
```

What do you think you can do in `magic()`?

Comment: Which operating system? On unix-like systems you can fork without going back to disk, but with windows a subprocess reexecutes python and the script and this means I/O (maybe not all the way to disk, it its still cached in RAM).

Comment: I would like to see a platform-independent solution, but I'm mostly running this on unix-like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On unix-like systems you can fork a subprocess and have it run the singleton. Assuming you've already imported everything needed by the singleton and the singleton itself doesn't touch the disk, it could work. Fair warning: whatever reason this thing was a singleton in the first place may nip you. You can let the multiprocessing package do the heavy lifting for you.

On windows, a new python interpreter is executed and there may be significant state passed between parent and child, which could have harmful effects. But again, it may work...

```
import multiprocessing as mp

#the singleton
def foo():
    crash_when_got_run_twice()
    result = something_fancy()
    return result

def _run_foo(i):
    return foo()

#the runner
def bar(times):
    with mp.Pool(min(mp.cpu_count(), times) as pool:
        return pool.map(_run_foo, range(times))
```

Comment: One more question here, do they share the same global variable set or they will be separately initialized just like when I start a fresh copy? I would like to know whether different processes will interfere with each other in this method.

Comment: I got different results from different implementations. Are there any difference between using subprocess spawning and running scripts fresh?